# Handle 3 different responses from one single POST request

Tags: java, postgresql, rest, post

I'm trying to change the following code so it only makes one query instead of two. The problem is, you can see there are 3 possible responses I need returned. The default is 404 at the bottom if no conditionals are met, and the second 404 response is returned if the login credentials are correct BUT the account has expired. The only valid response (200) is returned if the account is correct and active.

How do I combine the `SELECT` statements into one while preserving the ability to respond in 3 different ways depending on the user's status?

```
    @POST
    @Path("accounts/initial/{user}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public Response validate(@PathParam("user") final String username) {

        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = LicenseDBSource.getInstance().getConnection();
            statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ?");
            statement.setString(1, username);
            rs = statement.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                statement = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM members WHERE
                username = ? AND LOCALTIMESTAMP < expiration");
                statement.setString(1, username);

                rs = statement.executeQuery();
                if (rs.next()) {
                    return Response.status(200).build();
                    }
                } else {
                    return Response.status(404).entity("Expired").build();
                }
            }
        } catch (...) {
           ...handle exceptions...
        } finally {
            closeResources(...);
        }
        return Response.status(404).entity("Incorrect").build();
    }
```

My database contains columns including "username" and "expiration".

Comment: Have you tried using UNION? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp? Also: are you trying to solve an issue, say with performance or why do you need to combine those queries?

Comment: Appreciate the feedback but `UNION` seems to only aggregate the responses of two queries into one, but I fail to see how I'd then be able to distinguish which of the two `SELECT` statements returned which response. It also seems that `UNION` is irrelevant here since I could simply use `SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = ? AND LOCALTIMESTAMP < expiration` but if the response is `404` I wouldn't know whether the first `SELECT` statement or the second one caused it. In other words `UNION` takes two queries and returns one response, but I need a command that takes ONE query and gives 2 responses.

Comment: You need to either make distinction in your code or in the SQL query. There is no way around that.

Comment: I think I'm making the distinction currently in my code (right?)... but how do I make the distinction in my query to achieve the same results as I'm doing now, can you provide a brief snippet? Thank you

Comment: Btw. whats the issue with two separate SQL queries? Although somewhat redundant and boilerplate-heavy, your current code is very readable.

Comment: Please see my last comment asking about the SQL distinction if you missed it. To answer your question, I assumed one query was more efficient and would require less strain on my database if my userbase eventually grows. If 2 queries is *not* an issue at scale then I won't change it.

Comment: I think you are doing premature optimization. Don't do that. You save time and effort and move on to other engineering challenges :-) That is unless you have analyzed this method is some kind of a performance bottleneck.

Comment: Also related to performance: what kind of indexes you have in the table? Do you have an index for username + expiration?

Comment: Makes sense! I haven't analyzed so I think I'll work elsewhere. I'll add indexes now, I should've remembered this. Thanks a lot

Comment: Adding correct indexes is definitely better way to improve performance.

Comment: Awesome, I'll get on it now.

Comment: Cool! Feel free to update / open new question if need arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform two queries with just one statement, you can just use two subqueries. Your try block would look like:

```
try {
    conn = LicenseDBSource.getInstance().getConnection();
    statement = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT " + 
        "   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ?) AS user_exists, " +
        "   EXISTS (SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = ? " + 
                       " AND LOCALTIMESTAMP < expiration) AS user_is_current" ;
    statement.setString(1, username);
    statement.setString(2, username);
    rs = statement.executeQuery();
    rs.next(); // There will *always* be one row
    if (rs.getBoolean("user_exists")) {
        if (rs.getBoolean("user_is_current") {
            return Response.status(200).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(404).entity("Expired").build();
        }
    }
```

---

**Alternative**, use a single query, but this time you have two options: it either returns no rows (meaning user doesn't exist), or returns just *one* row (assuming usrname is PK) with a computed column telling you whether the user is current. That's actually cleaner and take less time than the previous approach:

```
try {
    conn = LicenseDBSource.getInstance().getConnection();
    statement = conn.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT " + 
        "    (LOCALTIMESTAMP < expiration) AS user_is_current " +
        "FROM " +
        "    members WHERE username = ?";

    statement.setString(1, username);
    rs = statement.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()) {
        if (rs.getBoolean("user_is_current") {
            return Response.status(200).build();
        } else {
            return Response.status(404).entity("Expired").build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Subqueries looks like the concept I was searching for. Thanks for the clear explanation and dual examples. Is using a subquery in this scenario more efficient than my original code, with 2 queries? Perhaps testing is the only way to know.

Comment: You halve the round-trip from your PHP program to the database (either TCP/IP or other inter-process communication mechanism). Imagine you're in London and your database in Sydney, even at the speed of light, every query already needs 102 ms round-trip; assuming no tolls along the way.